# Java prevent unused warnings

Tags: java, eclipse, suppress-warnings

So i was using Eclipse to create a simple program, in this program I have a object that has no other methods other than the constructor. Something like this

```
class Example{

public Example(...)
   {
      //Do something with the variable
   }
}
```

The whole logic of Example class is in the constructor, there will be no more methods for this class.

When i instantiate an object of this class, I get these "unused" warnings. I don't want to suppress all the unused warnings, I just want warnings to be suppressed when I instantiate this object.

Again, I don't want to supresswarnings where I use Example class as there will be multiple places where I use it and I don't want to riddle my code with these useless supresswarnings.

Comment: Maybe you can tell us more about what you do in the constructor. Would it not make sense to have a static method instead (`Example.doStuff(variable)`)?

Comment: Any specific reason for putting the entire logic of your class in the constructor?

Comment: preferences->java-compiler->errors/warning and there you can turn off warnings inside eclipse, but really re-design your code...

Comment: Instead of `Example x = new Example(...);` you can just do `new Example(...);` when you instantiate those objects.

Comment: @tobias_k Your solution works btw. Thank you, thats a nice little idea

Comment: @assylias I am not sure what i was going with, by using just the constructor. i finally did use a static method. I was trying out some sample code and it felt odd when i saw these warnings

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> The whole logic of Example class is in the constructor

That sounds like a poor design to start with. If you don't really need an instance, why create it? It sounds like you should probably just put the code from the constructor into a static method.

If you *do* want to keep the class (e.g. because you use instance variables), I would suggest moving most of the logic out of the constructor, into appropriate instance methods, but then possibly have a static method which calls the constructor and then the relevant methods.

It's hard to tell without knowing what your code is actually doing, but I *wouldn't* be looking to suppress warnings here - I'd strongly suggest refactoring the code instead.

Comment: My question was answered by Skeet!!!. Thank you your suggestion. I finally went with using a static function along with private constructor.

Answer (score -3):

you can use a single suppresswarning for the whole class :

```
@SuppressWarnings({"unused", "unchecked"})
public Class Foo {...}
```

Comment: "*Again, I don't want to supresswarnings...*"

Comment: "I don't want to riddle my code with these useless supresswarnings"